# Can't get scrollTop() to work with datatables .draw()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using the datatables plug-in to display content that is being retrieved from a server. I am using dropdowns to display the content that the user can select from. When a user makes the first select, I am taking the input from the select using the .change(function(e) {}. Then in order to populate the second dropdown with related options, I am deleting the row using .fnDeleteRow(), and drawing a new row that displays the first selection as a read only string and has a second column that is populated with dropdowns based off of the first selection.

First off, this is working fine and I do not need any help displaying the correct content in each row. The problem is coming when I make a selection on any of the dropdowns, the page refreshes and jumps to the top. I have created a function that I think should solve the jumping to the top issue, but for some reason it doesnt do anything. I am wondering if anyone has had any experience with keeping the scrollTop() the same while using datatables and specifically the .draw() function.

My function I have created looks like this:

```
function saveScrollPosition() {
    var scrollPosition = $('#tblLineItems').scrollTop();
}

function setScrollPosition() {
    $('#tblLineItems').scrollTop(scrollPosition);
}
```

I don't know what is missing because I am saving the scroll position and then setting it after each .draw() that I use.

Also I am initializing datatables like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myTable = $('#tblLineItems').dataTable({
    //some stuff
    })
});
```

Here is where I am calling saveScrollPosition() and setScrollPosition():

```
function addSelectCriteria() 

newSelectCriteriaCtr++;

saveScrollPosition();

var lineId = "newSelectCriteria_"+newSelectCriteriaCtr;
var addData = [];

addData.push('<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+lineId+'"/></td>');
addData.push("<select style='width:150px' value='1' name='selectMfg' id='"+lineId+"_mfg'>"+selectMfgs+"</select>");
addData.push("<select style='width:150px'</select>");
addData.push("<select style='width:150px'</select>");
addData.push("<td><a href='' class='btn btn-blue'><img src='../img/btn/btn-blue-med-icn-forward.png' alt='Print'>Print Barcode</a></td>");
addData.push("<td class='controls'><a class='delete' id='deleteIcon_"+lineId+"'>Delete</a><input type='hidden' id='deleteHiddenInput_"+lineId+"' value='false'></td>");

myTableAPI.row.add(addData).draw();

setScrollPosition();

console.log(newSelectCriteriaCtr);

$("select[name='selectMfg']").change(function(e) {  

    saveScrollPosition();

    var mfg = $("select[name='selectMfg']").val();
    var addData = [];

    myTable.fnDeleteRow(newSelectCriteriaCtr);

    addData.push('<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+lineId+'"/></td>');
    addData.push("<td>"+mfg+"</td>");
    addData.push("<select style='width:150px' value='2' name='selectBldg' id='"+lineId+"_bldg'>"+selectBldgs+"</select>");
    addData.push("<select style='width:150px'</select>");
    addData.push("<td><a href='' class='btn btn-blue'><img src='../img/btn/btn-blue-med-icn-forward.png' alt='Print'>Print Barcode</a></td>");
    addData.push("<td class='controls'><a class='delete' id='deleteIcon_"+lineId+"'>Delete</a><input type='hidden' id='deleteHiddenInput_"+lineId+"' value='false'></td>");

    myTableAPI.row.add(addData).draw();

    setScrollPosition();

    console.log(newSelectCriteriaCtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I was using a class instead of the div that controls the scroller.

```
function saveScrollPosition() {
    var scrollPosition = $("div.dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop();
}

function setScrollPosition() {
    $("div.dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop(scrollPosition);
}
```